# Trying to display REPLACED and ORIGINAL values stored from separate entries in one row (under different columns)

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies in advance for my ignorance but I am stuck on this issue. I have a situation where I have a table called Calculation (as shown below):

```
CALCULATION_ID      CALCULATION_NAME               CALCULATION_FIELD
      1                  Sample1                     Space
      2                  Sample2                     Comma
```

And I have a table called Value (as shown below):

```
 VALUE_ID       VALUE_CODE  VALUE         TIMESTAMP               CAR 
    1             'REP'        7           31-OCT-16 01:00 AM     Mustang
    2             'ORIG'       0           31-OCT-16 01:00 AM     Mustang
    3             'ORIG'       1           31-OCT-16 02:00 AM     Mustang
```

The Calculation and Value tables share a 1 to many relationship and are stored in a relationship table shown below

```
 VALUE_ID      CALCULATION_ID     TYPE
    1              1              Forecast
    2              1              Forecast
    3              2              Report
```

I need a view/ query that displays the replaced value (REP) and the original value (ORIG) in the same row as shown below:

```
CALCULATION_ID  CALC_FIELD   REP_VAL   ORIG_VAL    TIME     CAR     TYPE
      1            Space        7          0     01:00 AM   Mustang Forecast
      2            Comma      null         1     02:00 AM   Mustang Report
```

I already know that we can use a case statement like the one shown below (which works when im only querying off one table) but I am returning only nulls for 'replaced' values when I try to join all of the 3 tables together.

```
select case when VALUE_CODE = 'ORIG'
            then value
            ELSE null
             END         as original_value
     , case when VALUE_CODE = 'REP'
           THEN value
           ELSE null
            END          as replaced_value
   from value;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would probably have been useful to show the full query that only returns nulls, so we could explain what was wrong with that and how to fix it. Also, in your sample output, the second row is supposed to have ID 2, right?

Comment: why are you so helpful? :) can't thank you enough. but yes I went ahead and corrected my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the three tables together, and then use conditional aggregation to combine the 'orig' and 'rep' values when both exist:

```
select c.calculation_id,
  c.calculation_name as calc_field,
  max(case when v.value_code = 'REP' then v.value end) as rep_val,
  max(case when v.value_code = 'ORIG' then v.value end) as orig_val,
  to_char(v.timestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS') as time,
  v.car,
  r.type
from calculation c
join relationship r on r.calculation_id = c.calculation_id
join value v on v.value_id = r.value_id
group by c.calculation_id,
  c.calculation_name,
  v.timestamp,
  v.car,
  r.type;

CALCULATION_ID CALC_FI    REP_VAL   ORIG_VAL TIME     CAR     TYPE    
-------------- ------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------- --------
             1 Sample1          7          0 01:00:00 Mustang Forecast
             2 Sample2                     1 02:00:00 Mustang Report
```

I'm assuming there is always matching data; if not you can use outer joins if necessary to show partial data. But it also assumes there is only one match within the group - otherwise the aggregation will show you the highest value across all matches.

Comment: why are you so helpful? :) can't thank you enough. but yes I went ahead and corrected my error.